# Hugo pages not rendering when using layout

Tags: hugo

I am trying to add a page to my Hugo site, however, I am running into trouble getting the page to render the content (when using the layout - I can get the content to render without the layout). More specifically, I wanted to add a resume page to my site. Here is what I did:

1. I added a `resume.md` file to my content directory, with the following contents:

> ```
>  ---
> categories: ["resume"]
> date: "2016-10-02T22:55:05-04:00"
> tags: ["resume"]
> title: "Resume"
> showpagemeta: false
> layout: "resume"
> ---
> ```

2. I added a layout file in `themes/mytheme/layouts/_default/resume.html`, with the following contents:

> ```
> <section id="resume">
>  <div class="container">
>       <h3>{{ .Site.Data.resume.name }}</h3>
>       <div class="panel panel-default">
>       <div class="panel-body">
>       {{ range $i, $el := .Site.Data.resume.source }}
>           <h5>
>           <i class="{{ .icon }}"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
>           <strong><a href="{{ $el.url }}">{{ $el.name }}</a></strong>&nbsp;-&nbsp;{{ $el.description }}
>           </h5>
>       {{ end }}
>       </div>
>       </div>
>   </div>
> </section>
> ```

3. I added the following to the `data/resume.yml`:

> ```
> name: Resume
> source:
>   - icon: foo
>     url: bar
>     name: baz
>     description: foo bar baz
> ```

Unfortunately when I go to the webpage, the page has no contents - to be specific, the header and footer defined in `themes/mytheme/layouts/partials/{header.html,footer.html}` as well as the css styling from `themes/mytheme/static/css/main.css` all show as expected but the resume does not!

Any help would be appreciated. I am using Hugo version: v0.40.1 linux/amd64.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try inserting partials in your `themes/mytheme/layouts/_default/resume.html` file like this:

```
{{ $baseurl := .Site.BaseURL }}
{{ partial "header.html" . }}
{{ partial "footer.html" . }}

<section id="resume">
    <div class="container">
        <h3>{{range .Site.Data.Resume.name }}</h3>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                {{ range $i, $el := .Site.Data.Resume.source }}
                <h5>
                    <i class="{{ .icon }}"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <strong><a href="{{ $el.url }}">{{ $el.name }}</a></strong>&nbsp;-&nbsp;{{ $el.description }}
                </h5>
                {{ end }}
            </div>
        </div>
        {{ end }}
    </div>
</section>
```

You should see some changes, then try editing accordingly.
All partials are called within your templates using the following pattern:
`{{ partial "<PATH>/<PARTIAL>.html" . }}`
Please follow these specific GoHugo docs to tailor your code usage for [Site.Data](https://gohugo.io/templates/data-templates/) and [Partials](https://gohugo.io/templates/partials/#use-partials-in-your-templates). If you need to load local files, use getJSON and getCSV, but the source files must reside within Hugo’s working directory.